# Examples  of  finite  dimensional  non  simple  non  abelian  Lie  algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, big-list, examples

Hello, I  have recently  started  reading about  Lie  algebras. However  all  the  examples  I  have  encountered  so  far  are  simple  and semisimple  Lie  algebras. Thus  I  would  love  to  see  an  example  of  a  real  or  complex  finite  dimensional  Lie  algebra  $A$  with  the  following property :

$A$  is  non abelian  and  it  contains non trivial  ideals.

Comment: Usually, the difficulty is in finding the simple ones :)

Comment: @ Srifo B: Here is an exercise for you: given simple Lie algebras $s_1,...,s_n$, construct a Lie algebra with abelian radical $r$ and semi-simple part $s_1\times...\times s_n$, such that $[r,s_i]\neq 0$ for $i=1,...,n$. (Hint: think of the adjoint representation).

Answer (score 7):

A nice example to play around with is the Lie algebra of upper triangular matrices. It is solvable, so has plenty of ideals and things like that.

Comment: And if you take the strictly upper triabgular, then it is nilpotent.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is also a good idea to take a look at the following papers by Willem de Graaf et al. about nilpotent and solvable Lie algebras of small dimension over arbitrary fields:

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404071

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511668

http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.0361

Answer (score 2):

The 3-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra can be described by the presentation:

$$\mathcal{H}=\big\langle x, y, z\,\big\vert\,[x,y] = z, [x,z]=[y,z]=0\big\rangle$$

The derived subalgebra $[\mathcal{H},\mathcal{H}]$ is a central ideal spanned by $z$, and the whole Lie algebra is a nilpotent Lie algebra (thus not simple or semi-simple).

Answer (score 0):

Take any non-abelian Lie algebra $L$ and consider $L\oplus {\mathbb C}^n$. This Lie algebra is non-abelian, and non-semisimple because it has a non-trivial radical.

Answer (score 0):

To get a good idea about the relative paucity of simple Lie algebras (as Mariano says in his comment above), you could take a look at a list of low-dimensional Lie algebras.  For instance, here: J. Patera,R.T. Sharp,P. Winternitz, and H. Zassenhaus, [Invariants of real low dimension Lie algebras](http://jmp.aip.org/resource/1/jmapaq/v17/i6/p986_s1), J. Mathematical Phys. 17 (1976), no. 6, 986–994.